# How to display record from one to many mysql tables in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem in fetching records from database using php.But When I simply execute the following query into phpmyadmin sqls o it works but when I try to excute using php then its dipslaying error like this:

"undefined index experience.start"

```
$experience = "SELECT
experience.start,
experience.finish,
experience.isActive,
experience.title,
experience.nameOfOrgnization,
experienceprofessionnelle.organismeLogoURL,
description.details
FROM experience,description  WHERE experience.ID_EP = description.ID_Description";
$result =  $connection->query($experience);

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){


  echo $row["experience.start"];
}
```

Comment: In your last line of code try: `$row["dateDebut"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use $row["start"] instant of $row["experiene.start"] as MYSQL return column name not a table.column name

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
$experience = "SELECT
experience.start,
experience.finish,
experience.isActive,
experience.title,
experience.nameOfOrgnization,
experienceprofessionnelle.organismeLogoURL,
description.details
FROM experience,description  WHERE experience.ID_EP = description.ID_Description";
$result =  $connection->query($experience);

while($row=$result->mysqli_fetch_array()){


  echo $row["experience.start"];
}
```

**OR**

```
$experience = "SELECT
experience.start,
experience.finish,
experience.isActive,
experience.title,
experience.nameOfOrgnization,
experienceprofessionnelle.organismeLogoURL,
description.details
FROM experience,description  WHERE experience.ID_EP = description.ID_Description";
$result =  $connection->query($experience);

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){


  echo $row["start"];
}
```